# How to get string as sequence of UTF-8 codes

Tags: java, string, encoding

How to encode String to something like `\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435`?
I tried `Sting newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");` but it just return string I already have

Comment: Your example doesn't look like it has anything to do with UTF-8.

Comment: it's not UTF-8 but unicode

Comment: Here's an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Convertsthestringtotheunicodeformat.htm) which you can get by searching in [Google](http://www.google.com) like [parse string to unicode](https://www.google.com.mx/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=parse+string+to+unicode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=JlD-U6LzI-aS2AXCj4GIBQ#channel=fs&q=parse+string+to+unicode+java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` from apache-commons

Demo:

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("Введенные"));
```

prints:

```
\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also classic way that is putting escape characters before '\'.

```
  String oldString= "\\u0412\\u0432\\u0435\\u0434\\u0435\\u043d\\u043d\\u044b\\u0435";
  System.out.println(oldString);
```

output :

```
\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435
```